# Substituição e exibição de parâmetro em PHP

Tags: php, html, formulário, variáveis

Estou criando um codificador, um projeto pessoal para aplicar conhecimentos e aprender mais.

A parte de codificar está funcionando, mas a parte de decodificar não.
Eu executo e não aparece nada.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a encontrar o problema?

```
<div id="area">
    <form method="POST" action="resultado.php">
        <fieldset><label> <h2 class="a"> Escolha uma opção: </h2> </label>
            <input type="radio" name="condiçao" id="codificar" value="codificar"> <label for="codificar">Codificar</label>
            <input type="radio" name="condiçao" id="decodificar" value="decodificar"> <label for="decodificar">Decodificar</label>
        </fieldset>
        <label> <h2 class="a">Digite o texto:</h2> </label>
        <textarea name= "txt" class="cod" cols="100%" rows="20" > </textarea>
        <br>
        <button> ENVIAR </button>
    </form>
    </div>
    
    <?php
    echo "<h2> Resultado: </h2>";
    $condiçao = isset($_POST["condiçao"])?$_POST["condiçao"]:" ";
    $txt = isset($_POST["txt"])? trim($_POST["txt"]):" ";
    //conta
    $cont = str_word_count($txt);
    //divide
    $v= explode(" ", $txt);
    //junta
    //inicio contador
    $i = 0;
    while ($i>$cont) {
        if($v[$i] == "21UO4UTYEP"){
            echo "A";
        }    
        elseif ($v[$i] == "IPDQXS1QGL") {
            echo "B";
        }
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: No seu while está errado o ` while ($i>$cont) {`   precisa ser ` while ($i<$cont) {`

Comment: Nem acredito que não percebi. Obrigado cara

Comment: Tranquilo, isso acontece. Quando travar em alguma coisa, a dica é parar e ir fazer outra coisa, depois quando você voltar precisar ler o código palavra por palavra que você encontra essas coisas. já passei por isso também algumas vezes nesse 20 anos de programação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você atribui o valor de `$cont` igual ao número de palavras e o valor `$i` igual a 0, depois você diz enquanto `$i` for maior que `$cont`.

Seu código nunca entra no laço, `$i` nunca será maior que o contador.

Inverte.

```
while($i < $cont){}
```

Comment: Nem acredito que não percebi isso. OBRIGADO